# How to enable HTTPS on AWS EC2 running an NGINX Docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, certbot

I have an EC2 instance on AWS that runs Amazon Linux 2.

On it, I installed Git, docker, and docker-compose. Once done, I cloned my repository and ran `docker-compose up` to get my production environment up. I go to the public DNS, and it works.

I now want to enable HTTPS onto the site.

My project has a frontend using React to run on an Nginx-alpine server. The backend is a NodeJS server.

This is my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://${PROJECT_NAME}_backend:${NODE_PORT}/;
    }    

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
##############################
# Back-End Container
##############################
  backend: # Node-Express backend that acts as an API.
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_backend
    init: true
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      target: production
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_PATH=${EXPRESS_NODE_PATH}
      - AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
      - PORT=${NODE_PORT}
    networks:
      - client
##############################
# Front-End Container
##############################
  nginx:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      target: production
      args:
        - NODE_PATH=${REACT_NODE_PATH}
        - SASS_PATH=${SASS_PATH}
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
      - NODE_PORT=${NODE_PORT}
      - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    command: /bin/ash -c "envsubst '$$PROJECT_NAME $$NODE_PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - client
##############################
# General Config
##############################
networks:
  client:
```

I know there's a Docker image for certbot, but I'm not sure how to use it. I'm also worried about the way I'm proxying requests to `/api/` to the server over http. Will that also give me any problems?

---

Edit:

Attempt #1: Traefik

I created a Traefik container to route all traffic through HTTPS.

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

For the toml file, I added the following:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "ec2-00-000-000-00.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

I added this to my docker-compose production file:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.docker.network=web"
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:ec2-00-000-000-00.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
  - "traefik.basic.port=80"
  - "traefik.basic.protocol=https"
```

I ran `docker-compose up` for the Traefik container, and then ran `docker-compose up` on my production image. I got the following error:

> unable to obtain acme certificate

I'm reading the Traefik docs and apparently there's a way to configure the toml file specifically for Amazon ECS: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/ecs/

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling SSL is done through following the tutorial on [Nginx and Let's Encrypt with Docker in Less Than 5 Minutes](https://link.medium.com/mvRuzSv0VY). I ran into some issues while following it, so I will try to clarify some things here.

The steps include adding the following to the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
##############################
# Certbot Container
##############################
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./frontend/data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```

As for the **Nginx Container** section of the `docker-compose.yml`, it should be amended to include the same volumes added to the **Certbot Container**, as well as add the ports and expose configurations:

```
  service_name:
    container_name: container_name
    image: nginx:alpine
    command: /bin/ash -c "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - default
```

The `data` folder may be saved anywhere else, but make sure to know where it is and make sure to reference it properly when reused later. In this example, I am simply saving it in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Once the above configurations are put into place, a couple of steps are to be taken in order to initialize the issuance of the certificates.

Firstly, your Nginx configuration (`default.conf`) is to be changed to accommodate the domain verification request:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name example.com www.example.com;
     server_tokens off;

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
     ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

     location / {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri /index.html;
         proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
         proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     }
}
```

Once the Nginx configuration file is amended, a dummy certificate is created to allow for **Let's Encrypt** validation to take place. There is a script that does all of this automatically, which can be downloaded, into the root of the project, using CURL, before being amended to suit the environment. The script would also need to be made executable using the `chmod` command:

```sh
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wmnnd/nginx-certbot/master/init-letsencrypt.sh > init-letsencrypt.sh && chmod +x init-letsencrypt.sh
```

Once the script is downloaded, it is to be amended as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -x "$(command -v docker-compose)" ]; then
  echo 'Error: docker-compose is not installed.' >&2
  exit 1
fi

-domains=(example.org www.example.org)
+domains=(example.com www.example.com)
rsa_key_size=4096
-data_path="./data/certbot"
+data_path="./data/certbot"
-email="" # Adding a valid address is strongly recommended
+email="admin@example.com" # Adding a valid address is strongly recommended
staging=0 # Set to 1 when testing setup to avoid hitting request limits

if [ -d "$data_path" ]; then
  read -p "Existing data found for $domains. Continue and replace existing certificate? (y/N) " decision
  if [ "$decision" != "Y" ] && [ "$decision" != "y" ]; then
    exit
  fi
fi

if [ ! -e "$data_path/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf" ] || [ ! -e "$data_path/conf/ssl-dhparams.pem" ]; then
  echo "### Downloading recommended TLS parameters ..."
  mkdir -p "$data_path/conf"
  curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot-nginx/certbot_nginx/tls_configs/options-ssl-nginx.conf > "$data_path/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf"
  curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot/ssl-dhparams.pem > "$data_path/conf/ssl-dhparams.pem"
  echo
fi

echo "### Creating dummy certificate for $domains ..."
path="/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domains"
mkdir -p "$data_path/conf/live/$domains"
-docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "\
+docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm --entrypoint "\
  openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -days 1\
    -keyout '$path/privkey.pem' \
    -out '$path/fullchain.pem' \
    -subj '/CN=localhost'" certbot
echo

echo "### Starting nginx ..."
-docker-compose up --force-recreate -d nginx
+docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --force-recreate -d service_name
echo

echo "### Deleting dummy certificate for $domains ..."
-docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "\
+docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm --entrypoint "\
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domains && \
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/$domains && \
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/$domains.conf" certbot
echo

echo "### Requesting Let's Encrypt certificate for $domains ..."
#Join $domains to -d args
domain_args=""
for domain in "${domains[@]}"; do
  domain_args="$domain_args -d $domain"
done

# Select appropriate email arg
case "$email" in
  "") email_arg="--register-unsafely-without-email" ;;
  *) email_arg="--email $email" ;;
esac

# Enable staging mode if needed
if [ $staging != "0" ]; then staging_arg="--staging"; fi

-docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "\
+docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm --entrypoint "\
  certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot \
    $staging_arg \
    $email_arg \
    $domain_args \
    --rsa-key-size $rsa_key_size \
    --agree-tos \
    --force-renewal" certbot
echo

echo "### Reloading nginx ..."
-docker-compose exec nginx nginx -s reload
+docker-compose exec service_name nginx -s reload
```

I have made sure to always include the `-f` flag with the `docker-compose` command just in case someone doesn't know what to change if they had a custom named `docker-compose.yml` file. I have also made sure to set the service name as `service_name` to make sure to differentiate between the service name and the Nginx command, unlike the tutorial.

**Note:** If unsure about the fact that the setup is working, make sure to set staging as `1` to avoid hitting request limits. It is important to remember to set it back to `0` once testing is done and redo all steps from amending the `init-letsencrypt.sh` file. Once testing is done and the staging is set to `0`, it is important to stop previous running containers and delete the data folder for the proper initial certification to ensue:

```sh
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down && yes | docker system prune -a --volumes && sudo rm -rf ./data
```

Once the certificates are ready to be initialized, the script is to be run using `sudo`; it is very important to use sudo, as issues will occur with the permissions inside the containers if run without it.

```sh
$ sudo ./init-letsencrypt.sh
```

After the certificate is issued, there is the matter of automatically renewing the certificate; two things need to be done:

- In the **Nginx Container**, Nginx would reload the newly obtained certificates through the following ammendment:

```
service_name:
...
- command: /bin/ash -c "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
+ command: /bin/ash -c "while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
...
```

- In the **Certbot Container** section, the following is to be add to check if the certificate is up for renewal every twelve hours, as recommended by **Let's Encrypt**:

```
certbot:
...
+ entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew --webroot -w /var/www/certbot; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

Before running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`, the ownership of the `data` should be changed folder to the `ec2-user`; this is to avoid running into permission errors when running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`, or running it in sudo mode:

```sh
sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user -R /path/to/data/
```

Don't forget to add a CAA record in your DNS provider for **Let's Encrypt**. You may read [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/caa/) for more information on how to do so.

If you run into any issues with the Nginx container because you are substituting variables and `$server_name` and `$request_uri` are not appearing properly, you may refer to [this issue](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/issues/496).

Comment: Hi @yaharga ! In the second code block you have container_name: container_name, just wondering if this would be the name of the frontend container or if it's the container_name of another thing.

Comment: @elco45 It's just the name of the frontend container. I used a placeholder for service_name and container_name as I was attempting to not be confusing.

Comment: note that this approach won't work if you you use elastic beanstalk because every time a new application version is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk, configuration is updated, Nginx/Apache configuration is overwritten

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way would be to setup a ALB and use it for HTTPS.

1. Create ALB
2. Add 443 Listener to ALB
3. Generate Certificate using AWS Certificate Manager
4. Set the Certificate to the default cert for the load balancer
5. Create Target Group
6. Add your EC2 Instance to the Target Group
7. Point the ALB to the Target Group

Requests will be served using the ALB with https

Comment: This worked well for me. One thing I would add is that you have to select "Classic Load Balancer" (also labeled "previous generation") when creating a load balancer in AWS, in order to be allowed to create a load balancer with only one EC2 instance behind it. AWS now "encourages" you to pick "Application Load Balancer" which requires a minimum of 2 availability zones, and therefore 2 EC2 instances.

Comment: This worked for me, too, with an Application Load Balancer serving to an ECS cluster which (currently) has only one EC2 instance.

One gotcha to watch out for / cool trick: 
Set your Nginx to listen only on port 80, 
set your load balancer listeners (ports 80 & 443) to point to a target group, 
then on your target group, ONLY set a target for port 80 (so, NO target for 443). 

That'll deliver SSL traffic to Nginx on port 80, so you don't need to configure an SSL cert in Nginx - it's handled by the AWS Cert at the Load Balancer